# UITableView with customized cell inside Custom UIView Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, xib

I have been trying to incorporate tableview inside uiview xib file in Xcode.
I was able to get the table shown but unable to include customized cell in it.
here is my main code:

```swift
class homemoments:UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var posts: Posts!
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        posts = Posts()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "newsfeedcell")
        commitint()
    }
    
    //initWithCode to init view from xib or storyboard
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commitint()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newsfeedcell") as! NewsfeedTableViewCell
        cell.set(post: posts.postsArray[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.postsArray.count
    }
    
    func commitint(){
        let viewFromXib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("homemoments", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
        viewFromXib.frame = self.bounds
        addSubview(viewFromXib)
    }
}
```

when I run this code, my tableview.register returns an error saying that tableview is nil.
which is weird because initially my tableview.delegation & datasource doesn't work either. so I manually add them by dragging the tableview to file owner from the xib file to set those.

is this because we are not able to create customized cell for the tableview in xib? since I did notice that the tableview in xib doesn't have prototyped mode compared to uiviewcontroller.

**UPDATES**

My tableview now shows with the exception that there is no cell content shown.
I have searched and was told that to use

```
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "momentcell", bundle:nil),forCellReuseIdentifier:"momentcell")
```

see below:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commitint()
        posts = Posts()
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "momentcell", bundle:nil),forCellReuseIdentifier:"momentcell")
    }
    
    //initWithCode to init view from xib or storyboard
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commitint()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "momentcell") as! momentcell
        //cell.set(post: posts.postsArray[indexPath.row])
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue
        return cell
    }
```

here's the screenshot of my cell xib file
[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit

class momentcell: UITableViewCell {
}
```

and now the error is saying that

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "momentcell") as! momentcell
```

this is nil

Comment: What’s the name of the cell xib file? Do you have only one target? How do you create your homemoments view: in storyboard, other xib or in code?

Comment: Anyway you want your specific logic to be inside `commoninit` to be able to instantiate the view either from storyboard or from code.

Comment: BTW, you probably want to look into some swift styleguide, it is commonly accepted that all types should start from capital letter and make the use of camel case (`MomentCell`, `HomeMoments`). It is a widespread commitment across many developers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to access `tableView` before xib is loaded.
Try this

```swift
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    posts = Posts()
    commitint()
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "newsfeedcell")
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}
```

If it's not working than probably you have incorrect xib set up. You can reference to this [article](https://medium.com/better-programming/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960), it explains how to load `UIView` from xib quite detailed

Comment: thank you! now my table shows! but a quick question, my custom cell is not showing however. any idea why? this "newsfeedcell" was used on one of my other UIViewcontroller, was thinking of just reuse it. are we even able to use customize cell onto tableview inside XIB file?

Comment: in fact, simply adding text by saying   cell.textlabel.text =  "asdadasd" wont show

Comment: You have data source and delegates not set. I’ve updated the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Tableview will not be initialized yet In init if you are using storyboard

Please try to access it from awakefromnib or viewdidload